# Деплой проекта из Github на выделенный сервер

Tags: развертывание, git, github

Добрый день!

Ситуация обстоит так: необходимо сделать кнопку в веб части админ панели которая будет делать деплой проекта на хостинг.

Написал sh скрипт который выглядит так

```
#!/bin/bash

# Pull repo
#git pull;

# Change modes
chmod 0777 ./application/runtime 
chmod 0777 ./www/assets
chmod 0777 ./www/static/js

#php migrations YII
php application/yiic.php env=stage migrate --interactive=0
```

PHP скрипт запускает его так

```
$result=exec('sh ' . DEPLOY_SCRIPT . ' 2>&1', $output);
var_dump($output,$result);
```

Вопросы

1. Как сделать на вдс RSA кей при учете того что на сервере 2 пользователя. Для какого пользователя его делать (и вообще не помешали бы советы знающих людей)
2. Если понадобится для запуска скрипта делать exec от имени какого то пользователя, немогли бы подсказать как это сделать...

Огромное спасибо, заранее.

Comment: (Справочник)[https://library.linode.com/lamp-guides]
`man systemd` `man upstart` или смотря что там у вас на вашей системе.
Не делайте 0777 без надобности. `ssh-keygen` создаст пару ключей на сервере, публичный вам нужно будет подпихнуть вашему репозиторию.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Генерировать ключ нужно для того пользователя, который имеет права на запись в папку с файлами рабочего проекта. И отпечаток этого ключа добавлять в настройки проекта на github.

Что касается запуска скрипта, то делать это можно по разному:
 1. Выполнять скрипт обновления от пользователя, под которым работает PHP
 2. Выполнять скрипт от другого пользователя через sudo -u
 3. Организовать асинхронные задачи

Первый и второй способ имеют очевидные проблемы в безопасности (пользователь, под которым работает php, получает право писать в любую папку проекта, доступную через http), и, кроме того, есть риск завершения операций по таймаутам.

В третьем способе при нажатии на кнопку создается задание. Это задание проверяется по крону или событию скриптом, запущенным от пользователя, у которого есть права на запись в папку рабочего проекта. Задание выполняется, отмечается завершенным.

Организовать асинхронные задания можно разными способами, материалов на эту тему достаточно много:

- [Gearman](http://highload.com.ua/index.php/2010/07/09/gearman-%D0%B8-php-%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%85%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B8/)
- [RabbitMQ](http://www.phphighload.com/2013/08/amqp-rabbitmq.html)
- [Redis](http://habrahabr.ru/post/78050/)

Comment: Проще всего организовать асинхронные задачи через встроенный в систему crontab. Никто не мешает проверять апдейты кода раз в минуту.
Как там у топикстартера, нужно ли перестартовывать сервер при обновлении кода? Если нужно, то делать в скрипте сначала проверку на наличие обновлений, и если они есть, то обновление и рестарт сервера (через создание файла restart.txt в project/tmp или как там принято в php, или рестарт nginx, но для последнего нужны su права, а скрипт будет запускаться от www, так что тут нужно думать).

Comment: @pirj, про крон согласен, а рестарт сервера для php не требуется, он компилирует скрипты каждый раз при обращении к ним